# Cannot find module 'schema' or its corresponding type declaration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to create an Angular 8 project, but I always end up having an error when I try to compile the resulting app due to a wrong path in my `node_modules` folder; specifically in the file located at `@angular/cli/commands/add-impl.d.ts`, which contains this:

```
import { Arguments } from '../models/interface';
import { SchematicCommand } from '../models/schematic-command';
import { Schema as AddCommandSchema } from './add';
export declare class AddCommand extends SchematicCommand<AddCommandSchema> {
    readonly allowPrivateSchematics = true;
    readonly allowAdditionalArgs = true;
    readonly packageManager: import("../../../../dist-schema/packages/angular/cli/lib/config/schema").PackageManager;
    run(options: AddCommandSchema & Arguments): Promise<number | void>;
    reportAnalytics(paths: string[], options: AddCommandSchema & Arguments, dimensions?: (boolean | number | string)[], metrics?: (boolean | number | string)[]): Promise<void>;
    private isPackageInstalled;
    private executeSchematic;
    private findProjectVersion;
    private hasMismatchedPeer;
}
```

The line reading `readonly packageManager: import("../../../../dist-schema/packages/angular/cli/lib/config/schema").PackageManager;` always gives an error since the specified path can't find the file its pointing to; I checked and I actually don't see any folder called `dist-schema/packages`, and I don't know what its purpose is; if I change the route to: `@/angular/cli/lib/config/schema` the error goes away and everything works fine, but if generate the `node_modules` folder again, the error comes back since the route is again specified as before.

I haven't been able to find much information regarding this, and nothing at all that points me to a solution; I've tried upgrading my Angular version to the latest 8.x.x version, deleting my `package-lock.json` file, deleting `node_modules` and installing again and none seem to work.

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "opti-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "watch": "gulp watch",
    "dev": "gulp development",
    "prod": "gulp production",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^9.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.2",
    "@gvreddy04/ckeditor5-build-classic-all-features": "^16.11.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^3.9.97",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^1.5.5",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^13.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.2",
    "@types/html2canvas": "0.0.35",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.2",
    "angular-fusioncharts": "^3.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.14.1",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.6",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.1",
    "intl-tel-input": "^14.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.1.2",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "ngx-gauge": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-hotjar": "^8.0.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^2.3.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "gulp-file": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you updated your angular version? can you show your package. json?

Comment: @isAif I did update Angular to the latest 8.x.x version (or at least I think I did with ng update), I'll add my `package.json` to the question above.

Comment: Do you have `"node_modules/@angular-devkit/**"` added to exclude in `angular-maetadata.tsconfig.json`? Can you show this file?

Comment: I found something related to that as well, but I don't have any file named `angular-metadata.tsconfig.json`, that one seems related to a `bazel` library which I don't have

Comment: I think something went wrong. This version: "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.5" is way to high for cli 8.3.